# I find a problem in ros2 iron tutorial!

Tags: ros2

https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Nodes/Understanding-ROS2-Nodes.html

When you access the ros2 iron Tutorials - Beginner: CLI tools - Understanding nodes section.

You can find the command of Remapping learning section,
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node --ros-args --remap __node:=my_turtle
like this.

It should be like the upper one but when you access Chrome with Windows you can find the command appears with one connected under-bar.
The __node part will appear as I said.
So, the beginners can be confused because the node will start with name turtlesim not my_turtle.
It is just a looking-shape problem and will be okay with the copy or click the copy button but can confuse to beginners.

It can be my personal problem because of the condition of my PC.
And not that important problem.(So, If this is not an important problem.Sorry for bothering you guys.)
But if there is anyone who finds the same problem and gets confused.
Please tell the fixer that we can make the beginners not confused.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If the copy and paste from the page is correct then it sounds like a localization or rendering choice from your browser settings or the local font implementation choice potentially overriding the usual rendering. It's common for the double underscore to be turned into one longer line which might be confusing if you're reading it quickly.

Comment: Thx for your replying. I didn't know this is common problem. Thx!